# Parse push notification on lollipop powered Android device

Tags: android, parsing, push-notification

I am new to Parse Push notification. I have integrated Parse push notification and I am receiving this notification on all the Android devices except on Lollipop. I can't identify the issue. Here is my Parse push receiver class

```
public class ParsePushReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushReceive(context, intent);

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {

            json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
            Log.e("PUSh", "push has been received=====" + json);

            NotificationUtils utils = new NotificationUtils();
            //String message=json.getJSONObject("data").getString("message");
            String message = json.getString("alert");
            utils.showNotification(message, context);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushOpen(context, intent);
    }
}
```